# Is pattern matching better than Enum.split?

Tags: elixir

I want to get the first 3 bytes in a list of bytes in Elixir in my function `get_color(image)`, where `image` is a struct with `hex` defined as the list of bytes.

Now I know the pattern matching way of this would be something like:

```
def get_color(image) do
    [a,b,c | _] = image.hex
    [a,b,c]
end
```

My initial code was however:

```
def get_color(image) do
    {color, _rest_of_array} = image.hex |> Enum.split(3)
    color
end
```

I want to know if both approaches are just as efficient, or whether Enum.split does some other background work that may make it slower? Or perhaps it consumes more memory because it also has to create the other half of the list?

Benchee test for my code (based on answer):

```
Name                 ips        average  deviation         median         99th %
match           184.23 M        5.43 ns   ┬▒149.37%           0 ns          31 ns
enum.split      2.35 M          425.32 ns ┬▒15.78%            454 ns        614 ns

Comparison:
match           184.23 M
enum.split      2.35 M - 78.36x slower +419.89 ns
```

Comment: You can easily test that with https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/libraries/benchee/

Comment: Asking if both approaches are "just as efficient" is assuming that the *only* difference is the code.  Even the two code fragments run on the same machine may vary in performance if the machine is under heavy load due to other circumstances.  "Premature optimization . . . "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pattern match approach would be better for readability as well, not just performance. Running a simplified version with [Benchee](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/libraries/benchee)

```
iex(4)> Benchee.run(%{                                                          
...(4)> "match" => fn -> [a,b,c | _] = [1,2,3] end,
...(4)> "enum.split" => fn -> [1,2,3] |> Enum.split(3) end
...(4)> })
```

Yields that the pattern match is a tad better with a list of 3 elements, longer list's results may be different though

```
Comparison: 
match           916.17 K
enum.split      846.46 K - 1.08x slower +0.0899 μs
```

On another note, you could simplify your pattern match to one line function, where you [pattern match on the struct](http://learningwithjb.com/posts/elixir-is-just-cool-an-example-with-pattern-matching-and-structs) and read the values as:

```
def get_color(%Image{hex: [a,b,c | _]}), do: [a,b,c]
```

Comment: Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 0):

The Beauty of Elixir language is **Pattern Matching**.

Pattern matching approach is the best. When we are using Enum.split, we are accessing Enum module, this will become slower with the increasing length of string.

Comment: So accessing modules is slower? I thought those functions are available all the time anyways.

Comment: No exactly. Yes they are.

Comment: you can check  [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.1/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L196) what is happening behind the scene

Comment: Elixir provides macros as a mechanism for meta-programming (writing code that generates code). Macros are expanded at compile time.

Comment: Public functions in modules are globally available

Comment: Alright, but isn't `Enum.reduce` a public function? In `def reduce(enumerable, acc, fun)` they use `def` and not `defp` Also if macros are expanded at compile time surely there wouldn't be any further delay during run time?

Comment: yes. Check difference between def and defp [here](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules-and-functions.html).

Comment: Inside a module, we can define functions with def/2 and private functions with defp/2. A function defined with def/2 can be invoked from other modules while a private function can only be invoked locally.